# DynamoDB updateItem in Lambda fails silently

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to implement a simple counter with a Lambda function, but whenever I test it, the updateItem below simply does not work: none of the log statements in the callback are run at all, and of course the relevant counter in the table is never updated.  Here's my lambda function:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

let params = {
    TableName: 'Counters',
    Key: {
        'name': { S: 'global' }
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET val = val + :inc',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':inc': { N: '1' }
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
};

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    console.log("Invoked counter-test");

    dynamodb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log("In updateItem callback");
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        else
            console.log(data);
    });

    console.log("Updated counter");

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Counter updated'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

And here's the output of the test:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Counter updated\""
}

Request ID:
"80e92299-2eea-45e4-9c68-54ccf87199c5"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 80e92299-2eea-45e4-9c68-54ccf87199c5 Version: $LATEST
2019-05-07T11:34:21.931Z    80e92299-2eea-45e4-9c68-54ccf87199c5    Invoked counter-test
2019-05-07T11:34:21.934Z    80e92299-2eea-45e4-9c68-54ccf87199c5    Updated counter
END RequestId: 80e92299-2eea-45e4-9c68-54ccf87199c5
REPORT RequestId: 80e92299-2eea-45e4-9c68-54ccf87199c5  Duration: 275.91 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB
```

As you can see, no log statements from the updateItems callback ran.

If I try to update the counter from the command line using `aws dynamodb` it does work, however:

```
$ aws dynamodb update-item \
  --table-name Counters \
  --key '{"name": { "S": "global" }}' \
  --update-expression 'SET val = val + :inc' \
  --expression-attribute-values '{":inc": {"N": "1"}}' \
  --return-values ALL_NEW \
  --output json
{
    "Attributes": {
        "name": {
            "S": "global"
        },
        "val": {
            "N": "129"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript.

The method `updateItem` is asynchronous and you don't wait for the callback to be fired before returning (you start the `updateItem` operation and then immediately return a response).

If you want to maintain the callback pattern, you should do:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Invoked counter-test");

    dynamodb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log("In updateItem callback");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Updated counter");
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify('Counter updated'),
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};
```

Using promises:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Invoked counter-test");

    dynamodb.updateItem(params).promise()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Updated counter");

            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify('Counter updated'),
            };
            callback(null, response);          
        });
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
          callback(err);
        })
};
```

Using `await` (recommended):

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        console.log("Invoked counter-test");

        const data = await dynamodb.updateItem(params).promise();
        console.log(data);

        console.log("Updated counter");

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Counter updated'),
        };
        return response;      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      throw err;
    }
};
```

See also [Understanding Asynchronous JavaScript](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff), [Deeply Understanding JavaScript Async and Await with Examples](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-javascript-async-and-await-with-examples-a010b03926ea) and [AWS SDK for Javascript - Using JavaScript Promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and that last AWS documentation link in particular.  I (mostly) get async/await, but all of the examples of the dynamodb API I'd seen on the web (including AWS's own docs) made it look like a synchronous operation.

Comment: @ChuckAdams I doubt the AWS examples are wrong here, but I suppose it's possible. Can you point at any examples?

Comment: I'd amend to say the AWS examples aren't wrong so much I was misreading them, especially now that you pointed out the JS SDK docs where it states right up front "All requests made through the SDK are asynchronous".  The example I looked up elsewhere (which I can't find now) was in Python, which I more or less transliterated using another JS example as a guide, and that probably didn't help matters any 

Comment: For anyone else coming here, here is the latest version of the developer guide from AWS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/using-async-await.html